# Bootstrap Navbar not working when in mobile mode

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm quite new to BOOTSTRAP 5 (Web Development in general) and I am currently trying to make a simple website with it. I've selected a navigation bar but whenever I change my browser to mobile mode, the drop-down which appears does not work at all and all my elements in my navbar disappear. Any help would be grand!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Hello World!</title>
            <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <style type="text/css">
                #jumbotron{
                    background-image: url(bg1.jpg);
                    height: 25rem;
                }

                .center {
                  text-align: center;
                }

                #cardDeck{
                  margin-left: 1rem;
                }

                #logo-space{
                  background-color: blue;
                  width: auto;
                  height: auto;
                }

                #logo{
                  width: 300px;
                  height: 120px;
                  padding: 15px;
                  margin-left: 5rem;
                }
                
                #FMS-BTN{
                    width: 12rem;
                    position: relative;
                    top: 3rem;
                    left: 5rem;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        
        <body>
            <div id="logo-space" class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <a id="FMS-BTN" href="#" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
                  <img src="" alt="">Head to FMS</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <div id="nav-area">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">

                  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                      
                      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                      </button>

                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">

                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">DIVISIONS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">APPEALS</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">FEED</a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>

                        <span class="navbar-text">
                          <a href="url">APPLY NOW</a>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </nav>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </body>   
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to link the JavaScript Bundle for Bootstrap. The mobile menu only works with JS.

The JS Bundle code is:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

All you gotta do is to add the JS dependency to make it work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    #jumbotron {
      background-image: url(bg1.jpg);
      height: 25rem;
    }
    
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #cardDeck {
      margin-left: 1rem;
    }
    
    #logo-space {
      background-color: blue;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
    }
    
    #logo {
      width: 300px;
      height: 120px;
      padding: 15px;
      margin-left: 5rem;
    }
    
    #FMS-BTN {
      width: 12rem;
      position: relative;
      top: 3rem;
      left: 5rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="logo-space" class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <a id="FMS-BTN" href="#" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
        <img src="" alt="">Head to FMS</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="nav-area">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                      </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">

              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT US</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">DIVISIONS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">APPEALS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">FEED</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

              <span class="navbar-text">
                          <a href="url">APPLY NOW</a>
                        </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace class `navbar-expand-lg` with `navbar-expand-sm`. For me this is working.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS Media Queries to determine what action to do based on the screen size. Here, you would want to change the size of the nav bar based on the screen size.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) { 

*This is for phones, for example (you might need to find more accurate pixel counts)*

}
```

Comment: This is a Bootstrap Question. It is a CSS Framework so you should not even be required to use media queries. you have special classes for it: `xs`, `sm`, `lg`... Besides that, that will not make the mobile menu work. The mobile menu ins Bootstrap is depending on JS: